# audio state not saving persistently with shared preferences

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app whereby i need to toggle audio state with mute and unmute feature with a switch. For now, the switch state is saved persistently but i have been having trouble with the audio state as it doesn't unmute after being previously muted. Except, when the app is restarted, am unable to unmute the app. However, the audio state is saved when muted. What do i do?

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Switch mSoundSwitch;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    AudioManager aManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        mSoundSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.soundSwitch);
sharedPreferences =  getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isSound = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("sound",false);
        mSoundSwitch.setChecked(isSound);
        if(mSoundSwitch.isChecked()){
            unmute();
        } else {
            mute();
        }
        mSoundSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
if (isChecked) {
    unmute();
    sharedPreferences =  getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("sound", true);
    editor.apply();

} else {
    mute();
    sharedPreferences =  getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("sound", false);
    editor.apply();

}
            }
           // retreiving value from shared prefrences (sound)
        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("sound", true);
        mSoundSwitch.setChecked(isChecked);

    }
    private void mute() {
        //mute audio
        aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            aManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
        } else {
            aManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        }
    }

    public void unmute() {
        //unmute audio
        aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            aManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
        } else {
            aManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `boolean isSound = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("sound",false);` before you call `setOnCheckedChangeListener` .And you will know the state of your saved

Try this .

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    sharedPreferences =  getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isSound = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("sound",false);
    // edited here 
    mSoundSwitch.setChecked(isSound);
    if(mSoundSwitch.isChecked()){
        unmute();
    } else {
        mute();
    }
    mSoundSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.soundSwitch);
    mSoundSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                unmute();
                sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("sound", true);
                editor.apply();

            } else {

                sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("sound", false);
                editor.apply();

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: same result i got

Comment: it does not unmute after being previously muted

Comment: when i tried your code, i noticed that this time the audio state was changed when muted. However, am unable to unmute it except i restart the app. Any clue on how to fix that?

Comment: remove `sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("sound", true);
        mSoundSwitch.setChecked(isChecked);` in your code .And try it .

Answer (score 0):

You have saved the preferences but you have retrieved it and used from the `SettingsActivity` only.

To solve your problem, at the beginning of the app (eg. `onCreate` of `MainActivity`), check the value in the shared preferences and act accordingly.